# How to reorganize sublists and exclude specific indexes in those sublists?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, sublist

How can I reorganize sublists and exclude certain items from sublists to create a new list of sublists?

By reorganize I mean that I want to change the order of the items within each sublists across each sublist. For example moving every element at index 0 to index 1, and moving every element in index 2 to index 0 across every sublist. At the same time, I don't want to include index 1 in the original list of sublists.

```
Original_List = [['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]

Desired_List = [['c','a'],['c','a'],['c','a']]
```

I currently have this function, which rearranges and pulls out different indexes from a sublist.

```
def Function(li):
     return map(lambda x: (x[2] + "|" + x[0]).split("|"),li)
```

However, there are situations in which the sublists are much longer and there are more indexes that I want to pull out.

Rather than making this same function for 3 or 4 indexes like this for example:

```
def Function(li):
     return map(lambda x: (x[2] + "|" + x[1] + "|" + x[0]).split("|"),li)
```

I'd like to use the *args, so that I can specify different amounts of indexes of the sublists to pull out. This is what I have so far, but I get a TypeError.

```
def Function(self,li,*args):
    return map(lambda x: ([int(arg) + "|" for arg in args]).split("|"))
```

I get a TypeError, which I can understand but can't get around:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Perhaps there is a better and faster method entirely to rearrange sublists and exclude certain items within those sublists?

Also, it would be amazing if the function could deal with sub-sub-lists like this.

```
Original_List = [['a','b','c',['1','2','3']],['a','b','c',['1','2','3']],['a','b','c',['1','2','3']]]
```

Inputs that I'd like to achieve this:

[2] for c

[0] for a

[3][1] for '2'

```
Desired_List = [['c','a','2'],['c','a','2'],['c','a','2']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are describing is this:

```
def sublist_indices(lst, *args):
    return [[l[i] for i in args] for l in lst]

>>> sublist_indices([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 2, 0)
[[3, 1], [6, 4]]
```

If your sublists and sub-sublists contain all iterable items (e.g. strings, lists), you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten the sub-sublists, and then index in:

```
from itertools import chain

def sublists(lst, *args):
    return [[list(chain.from_iterable(l))[i] for i in args] for l in lst]
```

e.g.

```
>>> lst = [['a', 'b', 'c', ['1', '2', '3']],
           ['a', 'b', 'c', ['1', '2', '3']],
           ['a', 'b', 'c', ['1', '2', '3']]]
>>> sublists(lst, 2, 0, 4)
[['c', 'a', '2'], ['c', 'a', '2'], ['c', 'a', '2']]
```

Comment: Yep, that's correct. So I realized there are cases when there are sublists within sublists, so I'm trying to now use your function for those as well. All I could think of was: def sublist_indices(lst,*args): return[[i for i in args] for l in lst] that way I can just enter in l[2][1] for sublists that have sublists and l[1][0] for those that dont. I'm not sure if you have any thoughts on this

Comment: Well what are the rules for sub-sub-lists? Apply the same indices? Whether or not they occur on those indices? You could recursively call `sublist_indices` on sublists that contain lists themselves (use `isinstance(l, list)`).

Comment: Sorry about that. I applied a new example above which has the sub-sub-lists I'm referring to. I think recursively calling sublist_indices could work. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it (an example would be tremendous)

Comment: Could you also provide the input indices you would expect to produce that output? Do you just want every other item, whether or not it's in a sub-list? I think you need to make your rules clearer; that will put you on the road to implementing it.

Comment: essentially, I'd like to do: sublist_indices( [['a','b','c',['1','2','3']],['a','b','c',['1','2','3']],['a','b','c',['1','2','3']]], 2, 0, 3[1]) to get  [['c','a','2'],['c','a','2'],['c','a','2']]. I'm working on making the rules more clear above though.

Comment: You can't do that - you will get a `TypeError` for `3[1]`, as you can't index into an integer.

Comment: True, I guess it's not possible here. I think I can perhaps flatten the sublists and then apply it. I also tried this but it didnt work: def sublist_indices(lst, indices,indices2):[[l[i][[y] for y in indices2] for i in indices] for l in lst]. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: True! It was just a matter of time. Thanks for the read as well. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

```
original = [['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]
desired = [['c','a'],['c','a'],['c','a']]

def filter_indices(xs, indices):
    return [[x[i] for i in indices if i < len(x)] for x in xs]

filter_indices(original, [2, 0])
# [['c', 'a'], ['c', 'a'], ['c', 'a']]
filter_indices(original, [2, 1, 0])
# [['c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'b', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "reorganize", but this nested list comprehension will take in a list of lists `li` and return a new list which contains the lists in `li`, but with the indices in `args` excluded.

```
def exclude_indices(li, *args):
    return [[subli[i] for i in range(len(subli)) if i not in args] for subli in li]
```